# Whats wrong with my code to attach and use console from another process?

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc

I  have server process, its allocate console and redirect output and input to that console. With ShellExecute this server process spawn some clients, these client know server ProcessID. So, i try AttachConsole with next class:

```
Console::Console(DWORD dwProcessId)
{
    if (dwProcessId) {
        AttachConsole(dwProcessId);
    }
    else
        AllocConsole();

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO coninfo;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &coninfo);
    coninfo.dwSize.Y = 500;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coninfo.dwSize);

    int hConHandle;
    long lStdHandle;
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    FILE *fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );
    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    std::ios::sync_with_stdio();
}

Console::~Console()
{
    FreeConsole();
}
```

But it doesnt work, it even erase output to console from server process. Hmm.. May only one process can output to console. Is it possible to send output to console from many processes?

Comment: If that erases the console then it is working.  Changing the screen buffer of a console you don't own is unwise.  So is writing to it when the process that owns the console is writing as well.

Comment: thanks, i replace CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO into else section where AllocConsole called. but its still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open `CONOUT$` using `CreateFile`.  Attaching to a console does not change the starndard handles that your process has inherited.

Comment: Next code doesnt work too, no output at all even if i have only server without clients` HANDLE consoleHandle = CreateFileA("CONOUT$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
 if (consoleHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  throw 1;
 if (!SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, consoleHandle)) 
  throw 2;`

Comment: sorry, but inherited from where handles? I launch clients with ShellExecute, but not CreateProcess. Thanks.

Comment: ShellExecute ends up calling CreateProcess.  If you compile your client and server as console apps you will not need to deal with consoles.

Answer (score 0):

Can somebody say to me why next changes bring my code to work well:

```
Console::Console(DWORD dwProcessId)
{
    if (dwProcessId) {
        AttachConsole(dwProcessId);
        HANDLE consoleHandle = CreateFileA("CONOUT$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
        if (consoleHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            throw 1;
        if (!SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, consoleHandle)) 
            throw 2;
    }
    else {
        AllocConsole();
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO coninfo;
        GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &coninfo);
        coninfo.dwSize.Y = 500;
        SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coninfo.dwSize);
    }


    int hConHandle;
    long lStdHandle;
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    FILE *fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );
    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
    }
```

Now clients created with ShellExecute can write to server console.